# Using markdown/restructuredtext to produce a letter

Tags: pandoc, restructured-text, markdown, lettre

For simple documents, I like to use markdown/restructuredtext and convert it to LaTeX using `pandoc` (and LaTeX includes). For documents such as articles, leaflets, etc., it's quite easy. However, I would like to try and typeset letters (using, e.g. the French `lettre` class).

How would you adapt the markdown/restructuredtext syntax to do that (specifically, to pass the variables and open the `lettre` environment)?

Answer (score 8):

Markdown is quite limited when it comes to logical markup. It lacks
the necessary structural elements like “sender”, “receiver” etc. I
think it's not possible to create letters solely in markdown.

A solution would be to use a pre-processor like
[gpp](http://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html) to
create a logical markup which translates into different structural
elements of the final format. There's a blog describing this in
detail: [How I stopped worring and started using Markdown like
TeX](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/).
The following example is taken from the blog and gives you an idea
of how to use it within the document. It defines logical markup for
a file name.

```
<#define filename|`#1`>
<#ifdef HTML>
     <#define filename|<code class="filename">#1</code>> 
<#endif>
<#ifdef TEX>
     <#define filename|\\filename{#1}> 
<#endif>
The source is included in <#filename src/hello.c>
```

The downside is that you have to create the markup translation for
each output format. That's the price to pay for the flexibility.

Comment: That is an option indeed, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc lets you specify both templates and variables.  For instance, see the example here: http://pmagwene.github.io/blog/2013/02/07/pandoc-latex-letters/

Paraphrasing that link: you just create the latex template file with your desired letter class, etc, and then add pandoc macros (such as `$title$` or `$body$`) to include the variables (defined in the compile command) and content defined in the markdown file.  Then compile with a command such as:

```
pandoc letter-to-joe.md -o letter-to-joe.pdf --template minletter --variable=addressee:"Joe McShmoe \\ 9876 Mulberry Ln. \\ Salinas, CA 97654"
```

Note that since pandoc 1.12 you can also define variables using yaml headers.